# 415 Unsupported Media Type Error With Dojo and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, dojo

Im trying to post Json data using Dojo post i.e dojo.xhrPost() method. I found many solutions in stacks which have not solved my issue. Am passing the json data with content -type 'application/json'.Please find below code snippet of Client (JS) and Server (Spring MVC Controller).

I have added following jar in my Lib folder for JSON conversion

1.jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar

2.jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar

3.jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar

Point:Json data is passing is proper format. JSP is my view Resolver.

```
var map = dojo.toJson({id:'1',name:'er'})
var xhrArgs = {
        url : _context+'/exchangeRate/save-exchange',
        postData : map,
        handleAs: "json",
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json,charset=utf-8',

        },
        load : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error : function(error_msg, details) {
            alert(error_msg);
            console.log(details)
        }
    }
dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

Below is my Spring Controller Method

@RequestMapping(value = "/exchangeRate/save-exchange", method =

RequestMethod.POST,headers= { "content-type=application/json" },consumes

="application/json",produces = "application/json")

public @ResponseBody

Map saveExchangeRate(@RequestBody Map map) {

return new Hashmap();

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding the ACCEPT-header to accept application/json?

```
headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
},
```

Furthermore, your content-type header is incorrectly formatted. Use a `;` instead of `,`.

```
headers : {
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
    
**contentType: 'application/json',** 

instead of 
    
**handleAs: "json",**